# How can I remove black scuff marks from paint work?

Tags: chevrolet, maintenance, paint

I have an '08 Silverado, I recently had to haul a load of furniture a little over a thousand miles, using a tarp to keep it dry, and with the way my bed is laid out I have no tie down points. I attached the bungee cord/tie downs to the fender wells ( I know not my smartest idea...) but by the end of the trip I have black scuffs marks from the constant hitting against the bed. it seems it will come off with water and some elbow grease, but id like to know if any one has a better suggestion to get it all off, without ruining the paint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are marks on the paintwork rather than scuffs that have removed paint (which sounds like the case give you are able to get them off with water) then I'd use something like Meguiars All Purpose Cleaner with a soft clean microfibre cloth. This won't damage the paint but should be a fair bit more effective at cleaning it off then plain old water. If any tough specks remain after this then use a claybar with a good spot detailer.